# Resin printer adds a small block along the far right side

Tags: resin, lcd-screen, anycubic-photon

My Photon Mono 4k adds a small block along the right side and no matter what I do, it still makes it. It doesn't stop it from printing but is wasting a good bit of resin. Does anybody have an idea as to what's happening?

Comment: It could help if you [edit] in an image of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

A creation on your build plate indicates that that portion of the screen is illuminating. Either the screen has a defect that prevents the masking in that location, or there is spurious code in the creation of the print file.

You can test for a specific answer by running the files without the print bed or print vat. Cover the screen with a sheet of paper to protect your eyes, and/or leave the cover in place. The sheet of paper will give a more clear definition to the region being printed/not printed, reducing the glare from the UV lights.

Examine also the display on the printer while the layers are being printed. If the block does not appear in the display, it would indicate that it's not a glitch in the code creation. If the block appears on the paper, it's more likely a failed portion of the screen.

It's not out of the question that there could be a cable connection loose that prevents masking of that specific area, but it's pretty unlikely to be so tightly restricted.